# Angular Bad Request error sending data to server in a post request

Tags: angular, post, bad-request

my angular code:

```
var url = this.baseUrl + "api/ajax/PostProduct";
  console.log(tempProduct);
  this.http.post<Product>(url, tempProduct).subscribe(res => {
    console.log("Product " + res.id + " has been created.");
  }, error => console.log(error));
```

my server api:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route(nameof(PostProduct))]
    public Product PostProduct([FromBody]Product product)
    {
        product.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
        dbContext.Products.Add(product);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return product;
    }
```

I tried with postman and it is able to send the request.

Comment: What error are you getting on dev console ? under `console.log(error)` ?

Comment: message: "Http failure response for https://localhost:44307/api/ajax/PostProduct: 400 Bad Request"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 400
​
statusText: "Bad Request"
​
url: "https://localhost:44307/api/ajax/PostProduct"message: "Http failure response for https://localhost:44307/api/ajax/PostProduct: 400 Bad Request"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 400
​
statusText: "Bad Request"
​
url: "https://localhost:44307/api/ajax/PostProduct"

Comment: error: {…}
​​
status: 400
​​
title: "One or more validation errors occurred."

Comment: whatt should I do? The code seems all correct to me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that the values of the type of properties of the object to be sent did not match the type of the object expected in the api